# Creating a helix following a curve

Tags: math, three.js

I wish to create a helix that follows a curve, to see what I am after, this link has a gif representing it...

https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/202940-Spiral-Around-The-Curve

(I'm not interested in the animation, or other geometry just the resulting pink helix)

Ideally i should be able to have any shape curve, know a diameter/radius I want for the helix, and from them generate a second curve (the helix) that travels around it at a constant pitch

I am doing this in Javascript (threeJS) but i think its more of a general maths problem.

using the following, i can get a helix around a straight section, but it fails miserably when it changes direction/bends...

```
let helixPoints = [];
let helixDiameter = 30;

for (let t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.01) {
    let curvePoint = curve.getPointAt(t);
    let helixX = curvePoint.x + (helixDiameter * Math.cos(t*100));
    let helixY = curvePoint.y +(helixDiameter * Math.sin(t*100))
    let helixZ = curvePoint.z;

    helixPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(helixX, helixY, helixZ));
}

let helixCurve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(helixPoints);
```

I know I need to do something more to helixZ, and i think so it follows any curve, i may need to get the tangent at the points?

I just cannot get my head around the maths, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making a helix follow a helix... That was fun. There's probably a better way to do it, but here's my solution:

I defined a curve the same way you did to get the initial helix (the yellow line in my demo). Calling `getPoints` gave a bunch of `Vector3` objects, which I then put to work.

First, starting with the second point, I looked back at the previous point and formed a direction. This is close to tangent of the curve, though it will get less accurate if you collect fewer points from the curve.

Next, I crossed it with an `up` vector. I used `(0, 1, 0)`, but the orientation of your original helix may require you to use a different one. The idea is that `up` is always oriented against your tangents such that crossing them will produce a vector perpendicular to the curve.

Speaking of crossing vectors, that's what I did next, and got a nice uniform bundle of vectors. I then used `applyAxisAngle` to rotate the perpendicular vector *around the tangent* by an amount computed from the current point's index.

Finally, adding the original point position to the rotated vector gives us a point in 3D space equivalent to the rotated point, but following the original curve.

You can play with the different values, such as `temp` length and the intervals used to achieve different radii, frequencies, etc.

That was quite a challenge. Thanks for the exercise! If you have any questions, leave a comment and I'll try to answer them.

```js
// prepare the renderer

let WIDTH
let HEIGHT
let aspectRatio = function() {
  return WIDTH / HEIGHT
}

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
})
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(32, aspectRatio(), 1, 1000)
camera.position.set(0, 0, 50)

function resize() {
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
  camera.aspect = aspectRatio()
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}
resize()

window.addEventListener("resize", resize)

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity)
light.position.set(0, 0, 1)
camera.add(light)

scene.add(camera)

// populate the scene

let group = new THREE.Group()
group.scale.set(5, 5, 5)
scene.add(group)

let curvePoints = []
let rad = Math.PI / 4
for (let i = -10; i <= 10; ++i) {
  curvePoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(i / 5, Math.sin(rad * i), Math.cos(rad * i)))
}
let curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(curvePoints)

let geoPoints = curve.getPoints(500);

let geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(geoPoints)
let mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "yellow"
})
let mesh = new THREE.Line(geo, mat)
group.add(mesh)

let dir = new THREE.Vector3()
let up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)
let temp = new THREE.Vector3()
let amount = 0.25;
let innerHelixPoints = []
geoPoints.forEach(function(point, index, arr) {
  if (index > 0) {
    dir.subVectors(point, arr[index - 1])
    dir.normalize()
    temp.crossVectors(dir, up)
    temp.applyAxisAngle(dir, amount * index)
    temp.setLength(0.5)
    temp.add(arr[index - 1])
    innerHelixPoints.push(temp.clone())
  }
})

geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(innerHelixPoints)
mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "blue"
})
mesh = new THREE.Line(geo, mat)
group.add(mesh)

/* let geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10)
let mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: "red"
})
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat)
scene.add(mesh) */

function updateObjects() {
  group.rotation.x += 0.001
  group.rotation.y += 0.002
}

// rendering functions

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

let animationLoopId = null

function animationLoop() {
  animationLoopId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop)
  updateObjects()
  render()
}

animationLoop()
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: slateGray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow thanks, that looks great.  I am unable to test right at this moment, however one question that arises (which may be really stupid but here goes).. my curve that the helix will go around can literally be anything, so how would one know the up vector (0, 1, 0), when presumably that will change dependant on the curve direction?

Comment: I agree, and it's one of the areas for improvement. For the most part, as long as your curve doesn't change _general_ direction (meaning it doesn't loop back or anything), then a single `up` should be fine. There may be a way to get a more accurate `up` from the curve vs. the tangent you get from `getTangent`, but I'll leave that up to you to tinker, since this fulfills the original specified requirement.

Comment: @TheJim01 thanks alot for your suggestion and feedback, it was very useful