# How to adjust the periods of the two halves of a sine wave separately?

Tags: three.js, 3d, trigonometry

I'm using Three.js to create a 3D breathing bubble.

For the breathe in/breathe out animation, I'm currently using sine, like so:

```
const scale = 0.8 + Math.sin(t) * 0.5;
bubble.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
```

Now, I'd like to split the wave, so that I can allow a user to set the length of the breathing in and out duration separately (preferably in seconds).

What would the formula to achieve this look like? An explanation accompanying the solution would be very much appreciated.

Here's the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mirhamasala/breathe-bubble).

Comment: You have a lot going on in your CodeSandbox. Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) In a snippet? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992863/creating-a-helix-following-a-curve/50995724#50995724) has an snippet you can copy and replace the implementation with a sine manipulating a simple sphere `Mesh`.

Comment: There's not that much going, to be honest @TheJim01. [This is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mirhamasala/breathe-bubble?file=/components/Bubble.tsx) necessary to render a Three.js sphere. I also extracted the exact bit of code regarding the current sine implementation: `const scale = 0.8 + Math.sin(t) * 0.5;` in my question.